# Alias a generic function with lifetimes?

Tags: rust

I have a long function signature that looks like this

```
Fn(&Framegraph<Compiled>, &Blackboard, &mut Allocator<'_>) -> CommandList + 'static
```

I would like to alias this because it is used in multiple locations:

```
macro_rules! define_fn {
    (pub type $name: ident = $($tts:tt)*) => {
        pub trait $name: $($tts)* {}
        impl<T> $name for T
        where T: $($tts)* {}
    }
}

define_fn! {
    pub type Foo = Fn(&'_ u32)
}

fn foo_broken<F: Foo>(f: F) {
    f(&4);
}

fn foo_works<F: Fn(&'_ u32)>(f: F){
    f(&4);
}

fn main() {
    foo_works(|i| {
        println!("{}", i);
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c53c6fd076fbb761e08aae6f2abce79)

`foo_broken` doesn't compile:

```
foo_broken(|i| {
    println!("{}", i);
});
```

I would have to add an explicit type, which I don't want to do:

```
foo_broken(|i: &u32| {
    println!("{}", i);
});
```

Is there a better way to alias generic functions with lifetimes? The only implementation that comes to mind is to put everything inside a macro.

Comment: that not an alias but a macro. I don't understand your MCVE

Comment: That is some serious macro abuse, my friend.

Comment: @Stargateur trait alias is not implemented yet, so I need to find a better workaround to avoid code duplication of long `Fn`s. That is why I used a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without macros using supertraits and universal `impl`s. Using the example above:

```
trait Foo<'a>: Fn(&'a u32) {}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a> for T where T: Fn(&'a u32) {}

fn foo_not_broken<'a>(f: impl Foo<'a>) {
    f(&4);
}

fn main() {
    foo_not_broken(|i| {
        println!("{}", i);
    });
}
```

With this approach, you avoid specifying lifetimes on your closures, but must be willing to parameterise your higher order functions in terms of the lifetimes of the references taken by the function(s) they receive.

I realise this is the approach your macro is trying to achieve; however, it cannot cope with additional lifetime specifiers and significantly hurts readability.